# Use of TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy in WebLogic

Tags: spring-transactions

I recently received some code that is using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode ( non-transactional ) to access an MQ queue.  It is set up using DefaultMessageListenerContainer within a WorkManager set up in Web Logic.

I am confused... why is the code using TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy when the code is in non-transactional mode ?

Is there some magic thing about local and global transactions here ?

Any help will be appreciated.